# Understanding the base case for the following formula: $\varphi(n):= n \geq 3 \rightarrow (n!)^2 \gt n^n$

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic

In my book *The Foundations of Mathematics* by Kenneth Kunen, the following passage is stated:

> To prove $\forall n \in \omega \ \varphi(n)$, it is sufficient to prove $\varphi(0)$ (the basis) and $\forall n \in \omega [\varphi(n) \rightarrow \varphi(S(n))]$ (the induction step); then, apply the Principle of Ordinary Induction to $X:=\{n \in \omega: \varphi(n)\}$

where the Principle of Ordinary Induction is the theorem:

> For any set $X$: If $\emptyset \in X$ and $\forall y \in X (S(y) \in X)$, then $X$ contains all natural numbers.

---

I wondered how the above descriptions come into play for a $\varphi(n)$ of the following form:

$\varphi(n):= n \geq 3 \rightarrow (n!)^2 \gt n^n$...i.e. when proving the statement: $\forall n \in \omega [n \geq 3 \rightarrow (n!)^2 \gt n^n]$

In more informal settings, I often read analogies of the "domino effect", which tries to illustrate "what happens" after proving of the base case and inductive case $\forall n \in \omega [\varphi(n) \rightarrow \varphi(S(n))]$.

However in the statement $\forall n \in \omega [ n \geq 3 \rightarrow (n!)^2 \gt n^n]$, the first three natural numbers $0,1,$ and $2$ are are vacuously true.

Said differently, the first three numbers are, in essence, *true for a different reason* (as compared to numbers like $3, 4, 5, ...$ etc).

So my question is: **What should be my base case for a statement like** $\forall n \in \omega [n \geq 3 \rightarrow (n!)^2 \gt n^n]$?

Should it be $\varphi(0)$? Or should it be $\varphi(3)$?

I am tempted to think that the base case should be $\varphi(3)$. And then after my inductive step, I essentially **backfill** $\varphi(0), \varphi(1),$ and $\varphi(2)$ as being true because of their vacuous qualification. In this fashion, my set $\{n \in \omega : \varphi(n)\}$ would still qualify for the Principle of Ordinary Induction and thus conclude $\omega = \{n \in \omega : \varphi(n)\}$.

Is that the right idea?

Comment: The base case should be $\varphi(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

To show $\forall n\ in \omega$, the base case has to be $n=0$, at least formally. However, the proof of $\phi(n)\to \phi(n+1)$ can be made in form of a case distinction, one trivial for small $n$, one explicit check for when $n+1$ is the wannabe base case, and one normal induction step for larger $n$. But in effect, this works exactly as if we consider $n=3$ the base case right away. It would therefore be *overly* formal to use the full method. But it is perhaps instructive to try that once, but not more than once.

Comment: Just to understand then...there are three induction cases. The first is for $0 \leq n \lt 2$, the second is for $n=2$, and the last is for $n \geq 3$. Is that correct?